# Why are my normal pending changes recognized as "unresolved" by RTC?

Tags: version-control, rtc, jazz

I am connected to a project area, i've loaded my repository workspaces on disk, and am modifying my files in a legit way.

My changes are however NOT seen as "outgoing", but as "unresolved". I worked on projects with RTC before, so this situation is unexpected.

Anyone has any idea why all my changes are seen as "unresolved"?

Thx, you guys rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will be recognized as outgoing once you have check them in (in a new changset set or an existing changeset).

Actually, if you have existing outgoing changes, you can drag and drop unresolved ones to those changeset (see "[Advanced Gestures and Workflows](https://jazz.net/library/article/125/)"):

[image: draganddrop]

Comment: See also https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_scm_eclipse_modify.html&re=1&scope=null

Answer (score 0):

My experience on RTC is less,

In Normal case the "Unresolved" note comes in 2 cases
1. when someone else have modified the same project in different workspace (MainStream).
2. The delivered project and SandBox project/ content are having differences.

In your case its seems its a 2nd case you have modified something in the local sandbox which is giving you this unresolved issue. 
In your case you have to check-in i.e. putting .java content in your local server. 
if you select "check-in and deliver" then the .java will get pushed to main server which is considered as a deliverable mainstream in most of cases.(I dont know what is in oyur case.)

if unresolved is coming because of second reason then following are the options which you can use :
If you click on the Unresolved then you will be getting 4 options to resolve it, one of them is "Auto Resoved" which is more effective for .c and .h files and for other non UML projects.

Options 
1. Auto-Resolve 
2. Resolve with Proposed
3. Resolve with mine 
4. Resovled as merge

Auto-resolve is generally used for small changes for non-environment files.
(Tool is effcient to solve)
Resolve with Proposed : In this case the changes which arre remote to you will be reflecting in Mainstream. 
Resolve with Mine : In this case the changes will be taken from your local sand boz and the delivered will reflect the same changes on Mainstream
Resolve as merge : In this you compare the two unresolved documents and then you have to manual take changes line by line and then your proposed changes will be reflecting in Mainstream.

Kindly give comments if any query,